# ClickOnce: How to Get Double Clicked File Path for Single Instance Program

Tags: vb.net, command, line, clickonce

I have a single instance ClickOnce program with a file association.  When the user double clicks a file, I want to load the file.  This works great the first time around with this code:

```
Dim path as string
If AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData IsNot Nothing Then
   For Each s As String In AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData
       path = New Uri(s).LocalPath
       f.loadConfig(path) 'f.loadConfig() is the routine in my code to load the file
   Next
End If
```

The problem is if the program is already running and the user double clicks a 2nd file.  When I handle StartupNextInstance and check ActivationData the 2nd time around, it still points to the first file!

In both instances the commandline args appear empty (I've checked).

Note, this is for a ClickOnce Application, which I think use ActivationData to pass the double clicked file's path, at least for the first instance.

Comment: Look at the `Startup` and `StartupNextInstance` events of the application, which can be accessed from the project properties. The former is raised when the first instance starts and the latter is raised when a subsequent instance would have been started. Both give access to the commandline arguments for that specific instance.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, as stated in the OP, the command line args are empty in both cases. I don't think ClickOnce uses command line args to pass the file name for either the first or next startup events.

Comment: There's no specific mention of ClickOnce in your question and that last sentence doesn't read as very definitive because it makes no mention of how you determined that to be the case. Remember that we only know what you tell us so it is important that you tell us everything that is relevant.

Comment: Doh, you're right.  Thanks for pointing that out.   I updated the post.

Comment: Dang, guess this isn't possible? Seems like quite a shortcoming.